# React - How to map from two SQL tables simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pulling from a SQL table `device`, and displaying its content to a table by mapping from `device`. I am trying to add a column that pulls information from another SQL table, `group`, but I haven't figured out how to adjust the mapping in order to pull from both `device` and `group`. I am sure the issue is caused since `group` isn't declared in this scope but I cannot solve how it should be declared in this portion of the script.

Both tables shared a common column, `group_id`, and I have added `useSelector` for both:

```
  const device = useSelector((state) => state.device);
  const group = useSelector((state) => state.group);
```

```
                <Table
                  tableHeaderColor="warning"
                  tableHead={['Device Name', 'Location', 'Group', 'Release Version']}
                  tableData={device.deviceData.map((device) => {
                    return [
                      device['device_name'],
                      device['location_name'],
                      group['group_name'],
                      device['release'],
                    ];
                  })}
                />
```

An alternative fix I have tried is finding the `group_name` since both tables `device` and `group` share the `group_id` column, but it causes a `group.find is not a function` error. I am unsure if my syntax is incorrect, as I'm working from [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as a resource.

```
                  tableData={device.deviceData.map((device) => {
                    return [
                      device['device_name'],
                      device['location_name'],
                      group.find(group => group.group_id === device.group_id).group_name,
                      device['release'],
                    ];
                  })}
```

Many thanks for any advice

**UPDATE:**
Thank you for the answers and comments so far. Here is some additional information:

The reducer does contain the initial state empty array for group (`groupdata`)

```
  const initialState = {
    groupData: [],
    result: '',
  };
```

Here are the screenshots of the SQL tables `device` and `group`. They do not have the same number of entries, as `group` lists the groups that a number of devices can be assigned to. Hence there are many more entries under `device` than `group`.

`device` SQL table

[image]

`group` SQL table

[image]

Comment: So presumably `device` and `group` both contain data you need in the form of an array, and the number of entries in both the `device` array and `group` array are the same and correlate to one another?

Comment: Assuming "group" is an array this should work. Is it possible group is an Object rather than array?

Comment: If you're really talking about SQL here, you should just `JOIN` the groupname into the `deviceData` itself

Comment: I have just added some updates to the original post regarding some of these questions. @Bergi do you mind going into more detail on how that would look?

Comment: You haven't shown the step(s) where the tables go from the database into a react state, especially the actual SQL query (in the backend code?), so it's hard to tell

Comment: @Bergi no problem, I will spend time looking into how to implement `JOIN` for group_name, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

If you using `group.find` you need to make sure the reducer contains the initial state empty array for **group**

Comment: The reducer does contain the initial state empty array (added more info to the original post)

Comment: Try to use this logic it will give combine data 

data = device.deviceData.map(value => group.groupData.find(gid => gid.group_id == value.group_id).group_name)

Answer (score 0):

I think `group` is an object and has a structure similar to `device.deviceData`. By that assumption, `group.groupData` should be the array which will be useful to us.

What we can do is build a `Map` of `group_id` -> `group_name` which we use later for getting relevant `device` `group_name` in `Table` component.

Here is a code snippet which should give you an idea (this is a JS based answer. I think your use-case can make use of joins at sql level for less work here) :-

```js
const device = {
  deviceData: [{
      group_id: 1
    },
    {
      group_id: 2
    }
  ]
}

const group = {
  groupData: [{
      group_id: 1,
      group_name: 'Group-1'
    },
    {
      group_id: 2,
      group_name: 'Group-2'
    }
  ]
}

const buildMap = () => {
  const gMap = {};
  for (const {
      group_id,
      group_name
    } of group.groupData) {
    gMap[group_id] = group_name;
  }
  return gMap;
}

const groupMap = buildMap();

device.deviceData.forEach(d => console.log(groupMap[d.group_id]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a map in the actual JSX might get a bit confusing since you're pulling from two different datasources.  Also, assuming that the array in
`device.deviceData` and the `group` array share the same number of entries and correlate to each other, searching in `group` on each loop through `device.deviceData` seems like an unnecessary performance hit.  My preference might be to create my source data in a plain `for` loop outside of the `return` JSX, and then just plug it in directly:

```js
let tableData = []
for (let i = 0; i < device.deviceData.length; i += 1) {
  const currentDevice = device.deviceData[i];
  const currentGroup = group[i];
  const entry = [ 
    currentDevice['device_name'],
    currentDevice['location_name'],
    currentGroup['group_name'],
    currentDevice['release'],
  ];
  tableData.push(entry);
}
```

Then I would simply pass `tableData` to the `<Table />` `tableData` prop.